# MVC3 razor helper method to display email address with mailto passing variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get a mailto link to display with the persons name rather than the actual email address.

In my `details.cshtml` file I have the page strongly typed to my Supplier

```
@model TheWorkshop.Web.Models.Supplier
```

but although I can use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
```

to display a mailto link with the text value the same as the mailto e.g.

> < a href="mailto: me@blah.com">me@blah.com< /a>

What I want is to display the name of the person instead. So after hunting about I decided to try to make a Helper method

```
public static MvcHtmlString PrettyEmailAddress(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                                               string email, string name)
{
    var mailToLink = new TagBuilder("a");
    mailToLink.Attributes.Add("mailto", email);
    mailToLink.SetInnerText(name);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(mailToLink.ToString());
}
```

but the trouble is that when I try to call it in the binding like this:

```
 @Html.PrettyEmailAddress(@model.Email, @model.Name))
```

I get a compilation error

> CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

If I pass strings instead of the `@model.Email` and '@model.Name` then the helper works fine, but how do I pass variables into the helper?

Comment: Try like this `@Html.PrettyEmailAddress(Model.Email, Model.Name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling your helper like this:

```
@Html.PrettyEmailAddress(Model.Email, Model.Name)
```

Things to notice:

- Capital `M`
- No need to use `@` because you are already on the server

Also you probably wanna replace:

```
mailToLink.Attributes.Add("mailto", email);
```

with:

```
mailToLink.Attributes.Add("href", string.Format("mailto: {0}", email));
```

in order to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="mailto:@Model.Email">@Html.ValueFor(model=>model.Email)</a>
```